# x64dbg cannot open an exe file (but can attach it), why?

Tags: debugging

If I try to start debugging through the command "Open" of x64dbg, debugging stops without ever starting and a series of missing DLL errors are shown on the screen.

If I just open the program from WIN and THEN I use the attach command by selecting the process, debugging works.

Unfortunately I wanna "investigate" from the moment the program starts and not when it is already started.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant info about those missing DLLs errors? Any additional info in the status bar in x64dbg?

Answer (score 1):

You need some anti-anti-debugging plugins (such as ScyllaHide) for x64dbg mentioned in this page to counter anti-debugging attempts and do some patching if needed:
https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/wiki/Plugins